# UIToolbarItem not selecting when inserted as subview of UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, uitoolbar, subview, addsubview

I have a UIPickerView which has a UIToolbar placed as a subview. The problem is when I click on the UIbarviewItem nothing happens. I am not sure why, but if I insert the UIToolbar as a subview to the main view (`[self.view addSubview:toolbar]`) the button works fine, but not as a subview for the uIPickerView?

Here is my code I used to create the uipickerview and the uitoolabr:

```
dateRangePickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)-200, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 220)];
dateRangePickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
dateRangePickerView.hidden = NO;
[dateRangePickerView reloadAllComponents];

dateRangePickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
dateRangePickerView.delegate = self;
dateRangePickerView.dataSource = self;
[dateRangePickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[self.view addSubview:dateRangePickerView];

// Add toolbar
toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -44, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 44)];
[toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(selectDateRange)];
toolBar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barButtonDone,nil];
barButtonDone.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[dateRangePickerView addSubview:toolBar];
```

Could anybody tell me where am I going wrong?

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: [just referthis site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_picker.htm) i hope solve your problem

Comment: This code is out of date. I can't use inputaccessoryview because it is a readonly property

Comment: uipickerView not working ?

Comment: UIPickerView is fine. Please read the question

Answer (score 0):

I decided instead of adding a subview to the UIPicker, I placed the UIPicker and UIToolbar in a UIView to keep everything together.

Thanks all for your help :)